Blogger html search with parameters
i have a problem, i create template in blogger and there to search for text
url : www.my_blog.blogspot.com/search?q=title:SearchText
I have this code:
<form class="aps-search-form search" role="search" action="/search">
                <div class="aps-search-field">
                    <input type="text" name="q" class="aps-search" value="" placeholder="Example : Samsung Galaxy Note 3" />
                    <span><button class="aps-icon-search aps-search-btn" type="submit" value=""></button></span>
                </div>
            </form>

Result:
www.my_blog.blogspot.com/search?q=SearchText
But i need search with this parameters:
www.my_blog.blogspot.com/search?q=title:SearchText
How i can do that ?
my blog:https://techmag-blogger.blogspot.com/

You’ll have to use JavaScript for that

How? Daniel A. White
